# Saving Scrapy Items to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

In my scrapy project's pipelines.py, I'm trying to save to my scraped items to MongoDB. However, I'm not sure I'm doing it the right way, since after my scrape, when I go into the mongo shell and use the find() method, nothing comes back. During my scrape, scrapy's logs do show me that all of ithe items have been scraped, and with the save to json command, all my items are successfully scraped and saved onto the json file. Here's what my pipelines.py looks like:

```
import pymongo
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy import log


class MongoDBPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        connection = pymongo.Connection(settings['MONGODB_HOST'], settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DATABASE']]
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.collection.insert(dict(item))
    log.msg("Item wrote to MongoDB database {}, collection {}, at host {}, port {}".format(
        settings['MONGODB_DATABASE'],
        settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION'],
        settings['MONGODB_HOST'],
        settings['MONGODB_PORT']))
    return item
```

And in my settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'sportslab_scrape.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline':300}

MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost' # Change in prod
MONGODB_PORT = 27017 # Change in prod
MONGODB_DATABASE = "training" # Change in prod
MONGODB_COLLECTION = "sportslab"
MONGODB_USERNAME = "" # Change in prod
MONGODB_PASSWORD = "" # Change in prod
```

And in my scrapy's crawl log

```
2014-11-15 15:28:00-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Item wrote to MongoDB database training, collection sportslab, at host localhost
, port 27017
2014-11-15 15:28:00-0800 [max] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.maxpreps.com/high-schools/st-john-bosco-braves-(bellf
lower,ca)/football/stats.htm>
        {'athlete_name': u'Mike Ray',
         'games_played': u'4',
         'jersey_number': u'9',
         'receiving_long': u'7',
         'receiving_num': u'1',
         'receiving_tdnum': '',
         'receiving_yards': u'7',
         'receiving_yards_per_game': u'1.8',
         'school': u'St. John Bosco Football',
         'yards_per_catch': u'7.0'}
2014-11-15 15:28:00-0800 [max] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-11-15 15:28:00-0800 [max] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 283,
         'downloader/request_count': 1,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 35344,
         'downloader/response_count': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 15, 23, 28, 0, 613000),
         'item_scraped_count': 28,
         'log_count/DEBUG': 31,
         'log_count/INFO': 35,
         'response_received_count': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 15, 23, 28, 0, 83000)}
2014-11-15 15:28:00-0800 [max] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

python shell mongo queries. 'test' is just a placeholder I made to make the sportslab collection

```
>>> from pymongo import Connection
>>> con = Connection()
>>> db = con.training
>>> sportslab = db.sportslab
>>> print sportslab.find()
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000000002ADB438>
>>> print sportslab.find_one()
{u'test': u'test', u'_id': ObjectId('5466131ca319d723f08d2387')}
>>>
```

Comment: how do you do the mongo shell find?

Comment: This is actually my first time using mongo... so maybe I'm not even finding correctly. But maybe shell is not the right word to use here, I'm using accessing the mongodb through my python in powershell. I've updated my post

Comment: @pyramidface what is the output of `sportslab.find().count()`?

Comment: Oh snap, hold the phone haha. It's 163. So that means things are indeed saving. I was just too much of a mongo noob. Thanks! I suppose now.. I just need to read more about mongo >_<

Comment: @pyramidface good, but anyway, thanks for the detailed question. I wish more web-scraping and scrapy related question were like yours.

Comment: Could provide an answer (and mark it as such) to what you were doing wrong and what the solution was?