# When saving scraped items to Mongodb using Scrapy.Pipeline, an error came up

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, pymongo

I've been struggling with Scrapy and Mongodb for quite a while. I successfully crawled data from http://antispam.imp.ch/spamlist but when I finished Pipeline, a `KeyError: 'AntispamItem does not support field: _id'` just came up.
  I'm new to Python and Mongodb, and it seems that nothing wrong of my codes can be concluded from the error log..and I've already tried every solution from Google..I thought when inserting to mongodb, ids are automatically generated..but it seems not the case.I'd be really grateful if someone could tell me how to tackle this problem.
  Following is Pipelines.py:

```
import pymongo
from scrapy.conf import settings
class AntispamPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        connection=pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)
        db=connection['threat_ip']
        self.collection=db['data_center_test']

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.collection.insert(item)
        return item
```

Following is the spider and error log

```
import re
import scrapy
from antispam.items import AntispamItem
class Antispam_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='antispam'
    start_urls=['http://antispam.imp.ch/spamlist']
    def parse(self, response):
        content=response.body
        ip_name=re.findall('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}',content)
        content_list=content.split('\t')
        content_data=[]
        for i in range(0,len(content_list)-1):
            if content_list[i] in ip_name:
                dic={}
                dic['name']=content_list[i]
                dic['time']=content_list[i+2]
                content_data.append(dic)
            else:
                pass

        for dic in content_data:
            item=AntispamItem()
            item['name']=dic['name']
            item['time']=dic['time']
            item['type']='Spam Sources'
            yield item




KeyError: 'AntispamItem does not support field: _id'
2017-01-10 15:59:02 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'name': '223.230.65.17',
 'time': 'Mon Jan  9 01:07:38 2017',
 'type': 'Spam Sources'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 651, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "V:\work\antispam\antispam\pipelines.py", line 16, in process_item
    self.collection.insert(item)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 2469, in insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 562, in _insert
    check_keys, manipulate, write_concern, op_id, bypass_doc_val)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 524, in _insert_one
    doc['_id'] = ObjectId()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\item.py", line 63, in __setitem__
    (self.__class__.__name__, key))
KeyError: 'AntispamItem does not support field: _id'
```

In the official doc of MongoDB, I saw `"If the document does not specify an _id field, then MongoDB will add the _id field and assign a unique ObjectId for the document before inserting."` So does anyone could tell me what happened?

Comment: What does your antispam.items.AntispamItem model look like?

Comment: @Tanzaho import scrapy
`class AntispamItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    name=scrapy.Field()
    type=scrapy.Field()
    time=scrapy.Field()`

Comment: Problem solved! see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952080/saving-scrapy-items-to-mongodb

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but the SO question you link to doesn't clarify what the solution was (at least not to me). Can you provide an answer to your question (and mark it as the answer)?

Answer (score 3):

Found it short after I posted the comment. At least in my case, it was because I was trying to insert an `Item` as [defined by scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html). In the docs, you can see that [setting an unknown field value will produce this error](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#setting-field-values). MongoDB is trying to set/add an `_id` field.

So changing this:

```
.insert_one(my_item)
```

to this:

```
.insert_one(dict(my_item))
```

solved it for me.

Comment: I was having the same problem defined in the question. Your solution worked for me. Thanks.